# Make field readonly - checkbox - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="suspended" id="s" value="<?php echo $udata['suspended']; ?>" <?php echo $suspended; ?>>
```

And this textarea:

```
<textarea name="suspendreason" id="sr" style="height:60px" class="field"><?php echo $udata['suspendreason']; ?></textarea>
```

My question is, how can I make the textarea READONLY whenever the #s checkbox is **unchecked**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With your requirement, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#s:checked').length){
        $('#sr').attr('readonly',true); // On Load, should it be read only?
    }

    $('#s').change(function(){
        if($('#s:checked').length){
            $('#sr').attr('readonly',true); //If checked - Read only
        }else{
            $('#sr').attr('readonly',false);//Not Checked - Normal
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Field still disabled, when the checkbox is not checked

Comment: had a `$j` instead of `$` due to my environment with noConflict ;) - updated

Comment: Thanks! Worked without the $j

Answer (score 10):

I recommend making it readonly and disabled.

```
$("#sr").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#sr").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

simply because if someone is in Carat Browsing mode, rare, but yes I've had clients do this, they can edit the disabled fields.

And for the checkbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // check upon loading
        if(!$("#s").is(:checked))
        {
           $("#sr").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           $("#sr").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }

        // event
        $("#s").change(function () {
           if(!$(this).is(:checked)) {
           {
              $("#sr").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              $("#sr").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
           }
           else
           {
              $("#sr").attr('disabled', '');
              $("#sr").attr('readonly', '');
           }
         }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work. The field is readable when the checkbox is checked and unchecked.

Comment: readable or editable? if you don't want them to be able to read it, you would want this to be not visible. disabled/readonly only changes the fact of being able to edit it or not.

Comment: I updated my answer, It should have been .change not .click, sorry.

Comment: The `(:checked)` should use quotes `(':checked')`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#s").change(function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $("#sr").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#sr").attr('readonly', 'true');
        }
        else {
            $("#sr").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#sr").removeAttr('readonly');
        }
    });

    //triger change event in case checkbox checked when user accessed page
    $("#s").trigger("change")
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cc5T3/1/

Comment: The demo is not working. When the checkbox is unchecked, it it still disabled.

And when I tried it on my site, when the checkbox was checked, and user accessed the page; it was NOT disabled. Then I unchecked it, and it became readonly.

Comment: Sorry about that, the code and the demo should both work now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each( 
    function() { 
      $("#sr").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    } 
);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make it disabled = "disabled"

Comment: Yes. But how will that jQuery code look like? If a user loads the page, and the checkbox is checked already (value from DB) the field should be come readonly. But, if it is not already checked, and the user checks it, it should become readonly.

Comment: This just keeps the checkbox disabled.