# check to see if a particular checkbox is checked in a td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make textbox readonly or not depending on the value of a checkbox of personalLoan. If personalLoan checkbox is checked I want the text to be not readonly. If it is unchecked then I want the text box to be readonly. Here is one of the rows

```
<tr id="mytableRows">
    <td class="even"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="homeLoan"  ></td>
    <td class="odd"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="autoLoan"  ></td>
    <td class="even"><input type="checkbox"  value="true" name="personalLoan"  ></td>
    <td class="odd"><input type="checkbox"  value="true" name="noLoan"  ></td>
    <td class="odd"><input type="text" name="peronalAmount" value="1"  readonly></td>
</tr>
```

I so far has this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test tr').click(function (event) {
        $(this).find(':checkbox').each(function(p){
            if($(this).attr('name') == 'personalLoan'){
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    alert("checked");
                }else{
                    alert("unchecked");
                }
            }
         });
    });
});
```

This tells me the current status of the checkbox but what I really need is to know onchange of the personalLoan checkbox so I can make the textbox readonly or not in that row (td)

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make field readonly - checkbox - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419383/make-field-readonly-checkbox-jquery)

Comment: [or a dozen other similar posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=make+checkbox+readonly)

Comment: In what way is this question 'very different'? *If* it's different, don't simply tell us to read more closely, *explain* the differences. We're not trying to close your question vindictively, but we may misunderstand or simply *miss* the differences. Incidentally, I suspect you may have a typo in the name of your text-input, `peronalLoan` should, I imagine, be `personalLoan`?

Comment: It sounds like you want to set/unset the `readonly` attribute of an input based on its `checked` state in response to a `change` event. If that is correct, literally 100% of the information you need to solve your problem is in the linked question. If I've misunderstood, please clarify!

Comment: David take you time and read. Its for the different rows with onchange event and I have tried all those solutions and nothing is seems to be working with what I am asking here. thanks

Comment: @Autolycus as the OP, the onus is on you to demonstrate that you have a unique problem. Don't tell other members to "take [their] time and read." If you have tried other solutions, document what you've tried and how/why it didn't work. Surely with over 2000 rep this process is not _completely_ foreign to you?

Comment: I *did* read this question. And the other. And, yet, a few of the *others*, linked-to by Mathletics. I don't, though, see the difference between this question and the one you mention in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my own sanity, here is what I understand the solution to be.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]', '.test').on('change', function(e) {
    if (this.name === 'personalLoan') {
       $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('readonly', !this.checked);
    }
});
```

Assuming a table with class `test`, this allows input when `personalLoan` is checked, and toggles to readonly when unchecked.

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjFDg/). (I've highlighted the checkbox in red.)

If this isn't it, then I really have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I came up with almost same solution. But yours is much elegant. I will use yours

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this is exactly the same problem as the one I linked to earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you really want radio buttons, not checkboxes, and that the amount field should be set to disabled rather than readonly if the user selects "no loan".

Anyhow, here's an approach you can take. I've put the code in–line for convenience, it can re-implemented in jQuery or whatever you want, it's just an example of how to do what you seem to be trying to do.

The timeout is used so that the one click event can be used for any element in the form, including the reset button.

```
<form  onclick="
  var form = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    form.personalAmount.readOnly = form.loanType[3].checked;
  },0);
 ">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="homeLoan" name="loanType">Home</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="autoLoan" name="loanType">Auto</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="personalLoan" name="loanType">Personal</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="true" name="loanType">None</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="personalAmount" readonly></td>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <input type="reset">
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer RobG. I however was able to code it with checkboxes. I will add my answer here to help community.